# Smoothing zone edges

Tags: raster, gdal, polygonize

I am currently recreating a hazard map that was processed by another program.

Is there a tool/plugin available that can be used to smoothen out the rough edges of the grids?

Attached is the current map and the wanted result.

[image: Current Map]
[image: Wanted Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try some kind of filter. For example SAGA:s simple filter:

[image]

Comment: The weird dips around the edges suggests that the desired result image has had cubic resampling which over accentuates sudden changes, I think yours looks nice, how is it at the edges?

Comment: That is the whole raster showing in the screenshot

Comment: The filter worked, thank you very much for your help! @MichaelStimson, ah got it. Still learning the know about of qgis, again thank you very much guys for your help!